# Static svg file not rendering from spark-java

Tags: embedded-jetty, spark-java

I am new to web programming, and have run into a problem with the serving of a static svg file from spark-java 2.5 that does not seem to be present if I use python SimpleHTTP webserver instead.

The svg image file served from my spark-java application does not render in the browser - standard graphic for missing content is shown instead.

What I have tried:

1. If I serve the svg directly by opening "http://localhost:4567/amcharts/images/dragIconRoundBig.svg" in the browser, the image does render.
2. When the same image file is opened from my index.html page through the following html (part of svg element):

   ```
   <g aria-label="Zoom chart using cursor arrows" role="menuitem" 
        transform="translate(-7,3)" visibility="visible">
     <image x="0" y="0" width="35" height="35" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
        xlink:href="http://localhost:4567/amcharts/images/dragIconRoundBig.svg"></image>
     <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="25" height="40" rx="0" ry="0" stroke-width="0" 
        fill="#000" stroke="#000" fill-opacity="0.005" stroke-opacity="0.005" 
        transform="translate(5,-2)"></rect>
   </g>
   ```

it does not render. There are no http or other errors as far as I can see.

3. If I repeat step 2 on a different browser (tried Chrome and Safari), or after disabling AddBlocker, the result is the same.
4. If I repeat step 2 with python's built in SimpleHTTP webserver instead of spark-java, serving the same static content, everything works perfectly.
5. I compared the response headers of the svg files as served from:

   spark-java:

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Date: Wed, 11 May 2016 15:31:00 GMT
   Content-Encoding: gzip
   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
   Server: Jetty(9.3.6.v20151106)
   ```

   and python SimpleHTTP:

   ```
   Content-Length:679
   Content-type:image/svg+xml
   Date:Thu, 12 May 2016 07:46:02 GMT
   Last-Modified:Wed, 11 May 2016 13:42:27 GMT
   Server:SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/2.7.9
   ```

Could the problem be that the spark-java one does not have a Content-type specified? Is this because it is chunking?

What I would really like to know is how to get this to work?

Comment: I had a similar problem, in wich Spark is not able to set the content type of static elements properly. I suggest you to try this with spark 2.3. Please share the results.

Comment: The problem disappears when using spark-java 2.3. @Laercio, thanks, very much for the suggestion. I also tried version 2.4 and can report that the problem is present there as well as in 2.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just downgrade to Spark 2.3 for a while. This issue is already tracked at [Github](https://github.com/perwendel/spark/issues/550). Soon we will be able to upgrade to spark 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for me too. But what about staticFiles.expireTime(ms); What is the alternative way for caching in 2.3 I couldn't find